# Splitting JSON string into observable array

Tags: json, knockout.js

The below fiddle should shows lists of items.

However, the lists are in string format and haven't yet been split. I've tried to split them without success.

One thing I tried was to split the string to an observable array within the `map` function. Is this the right approach?

```
self.splitValues = ko.observableArray();

var mappedItemLists = $.map(data, function(i) {
    return new ItemList(i.title, self.splitValues(i.item.split(" ")))
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bGsRH/428/

**Matt's answer accepted.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely clear what you actually wanted to do here. Is this what you where looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/bGsRH/429/

I did this to split your values:

```
        var mappedTasks = $.map(data, function(item) {
            return new ItemList({ 
                title: item.title,
                items: item.items.split(" ")
            });
        });
```

(Note: you could have also just changed the ItemList function to take two arguments)

And then in your binding, you need to `foreach` bindings:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: itemlists, visible: itemlists().length > 0">
    <li><span data-bind="text: title"></span>
        <ul data-bind="foreach: items">
            <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

If you want the nested list to display as a list.